# Como monitorar mudanças no banco de dados sem fazer consultas abusivas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho um código que acessa o banco de dados a cada segundo e me retorna o numero de linhas de uma tabela, o problema é que um numero abusivo de requisições e consultas são feitas no banco de dados para monitorar mudanças nas linhas, preciso de algo que monitore mudanças no banco de dados e me retorne somente o resultado quando houver mudanças no numero de linhas, como posso fazer isso ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar **Triggers**.

**Trigger** é um procedimento que é invocado antes ou depois de uma requisição DML (*insert*, *update* ou *delete*) acontecer. Vale ressaltar que o *trigger* é sempre atrelado a uma tabela. Na circunstância apresentada cairia perfeitamente o seu uso.

Resumindo, você terá que criar um trigger para cada comando de *insert* ou *delete* da tabela, a fim de fazer o controle das linhas.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possibilidade seria utilizar [sockets](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/sockets.examples.php), ou seja, manter o canal de comunicação aberto, para evitar fazer novas requisições (com alta frequencia). Embora seja complicado para usar em hospedagem compartilhada. Talvez a melhor solução para você seja usar algum serviço de notificação push, como o [parse](http://parseplatform.org/), embora seja trabalhoso implementar em [php](http://docs.parseplatform.org/php/guide/) e [javascript](http://docs.parseplatform.org/js/guide/). Em conjunto com a resposta do @Altieri, é o que você precisa.